# Azure Workbook - Auto Refresh and Option For Import/Export

Tags: azure, azure-monitor-workbooks

We have created several workbooks (KQL queries written against the log analytics workspace) and created the visualization. Also, we pinned the visualization to the azure dashboard where we had the few observation and need clarification on same:

1. We came across one KB(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualizations)
   where it's clearly written that auto-refresh feature is not available for the workbook(available for azure dashboard). Is there a way to refresh the workbook programmatically or via API call to ensure that workbook visualizations are showing accurate data?
2. Is there a way to import/export the workbooks(like Azure dashboard-flexibility to import/export JSON file) from one subscription to others(Provided we meet the pre-requisite like subscription ID, ResourceGroup, and Log analytics workspace)?

Your response would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. workbooks DOES support auto-refresh, it is available in the top toolbar.  (Edited 10/20/2021, i forgot i had this answer from before where i said it WASNT a feature (it wasn't back then!))
2. yes, workbooks are exportable as either just the JSON content of the workbook, or an ARM template that you can modify and import somewhere else.

to export, go into edit mode, and then use the "Advanced Mode" button on the tool bar.  It will by default show you the JSON representation of the workbook.  copy+paste that to notepad/etc, and then go to the place you want the new workbook to appear.  create a new empty workbook there, go into edit, advanced mode again, paste the JSON content and press "Apply".

if you used specific resources in parts of the workbook, you might have to fix them up in the new place.  if you were "inheriting" resources from the default behavior of workbooks, you shouldn't have to (like if you are just copying a workbook from one workspace to another).

If you have a common workbook that you want to be generally available in a lot of places, instead of copy+paste, look at using "[Workbook Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/workbooks-automate)" (not the same as "ARM Templates", ARM templates are a generic way of deploying any kind of azure resource, "Workbook Templates" are a specific kind of resource)