# How to export ARM template of an Azure Workbook?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitor-workbooks

I am trying to export ARM templates of Azure Workbooks.
Tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/workbooks/get
But the response does not have the ARM template.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, you can export the Azure Workbook.
- You can export it by two ways, either by JSON content of the workbook, or an ARM template of the workbook.
- Go to your Workbook >in the left panel click Workbook > Edit > and select code tab.
- Here you can find the general and ARM template of your workbook, from there you can export the Azure workbook template.

Please find the screenshot to export Azure Workbook.

[image]

**References:**
[Azure Workbook - Auto Refresh and Option For Import/Export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62787819/azure-workbook-auto-refresh-and-option-for-import-export)